# Python - Round Function displaying unwanted scientific notation

Tags: python, function, rounding, scientific-notation

I'm having issues with the round() function in python. When I round a number to a number of decimal places (with the intent to take out trailing zeroes) the output is usually given in scientific notation. e.g.:

round(75435000000.00, -6) = 7.5435E+10

I need to have the output in normal notation, i.e. 75435000000. I'm using the decimal module for the Decimal data type for the numbers involved, and inside this module is the .normalize() method, which takes out trailing zeroes and converts scientific notation to normal notation, but I cannot get it to work.

Thanks for any help,
Harry

Comment: Only a comment... which version of python are you use? and which OS? On linux and trying both python 2.7 and python 3.6 I obtain alway the value without scientific notation. `>>> round(75435000000.00, -6)
75435000000.0
`

Comment: Note: In python 3.6 `>>> round(75435000000.00)
75435000000`, because as doc string says without the optional argument round returns an int.

Comment: The `round` function **doesn't display anything**. You'll need to tell us what you *are* using to display the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `decimal.Decimal` numbers have a sign, digits and exponent. A given decimal number can be written in more than one way e.g. 1230E0 or 123E1 and these (while comparing equal) have different representations in the `decimal` module.

This is deliberate; the semantic difference being significance. (As in exactly 100.00 down to two places after the dot vs 100 ballpark).

The same applies to the numbers in your example before and after the rounding operation. By rounding you are stripping significance.
`decimal` switches to scientific notation because it is the only way to avoid displaying trailing zeros that are not signifying significance.

```
x = decimal.Decimal('75435000000.00')
x
# Decimal('75435000000.00')
y = round(x, -6)
y
# Decimal('7.5435E+10')
```

The difference in representations between `x` and `y` can be seen using `as_tuple`:

```
x.as_tuple()
# DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(7, 5, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), exponent=-2)
y.as_tuple()
# DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(7, 5, 4, 3, 5), exponent=6)
```

`y` which has no trailing zeros is considered the normalized representation.

```
x.normalize()
# Decimal('7.5435E+10')
```

But `quantize` can get you back to your preferred form.

```
z = y.quantize(0)
z
# Decimal('75435000000')
```

Or, if you need two digits after the dot:

```
y.quantize(decimal.Decimal('0.00'))
# Decimal('75435000000.00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounding a raw number works the way you want it to, so you could do this:

```
def round_decimal(n, places):
    return Decimal(round(float(n), places))
```

Convert it to a float, round, then back to decimal.

Comment: `print(f"{round( Decimal(round(float(duration), 5)),5)} [s]")` Outputs: `0.00004`